# EF Core custom results from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core which I believe is also known as EF 7?  Anyways, I have a stored procedure that returns custom results that will not identify with any specific table.  How am I supposed to access those results and how should I call the sql command?

Normally we have to use .FromSql but that is only available on entities, eg. _context.User.FromSql().  I don't have an entity for it.

So I tried building a dbset/entity for the results, but again, there is no associated table, and there is also no "Key". How am I supposed to parse the data then of the custom results?

Comment: EF Core is still pre-release.  There are many things missing.  The Order data annotation hasn't even been added yet.  Personally, I don't use EF for stored procedures.  It's just a useless extra layer that kills efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, I'm open to any ideas. What can I use instead? Is the only option to scrap the entire project and restart with a different version of ef?

Comment: I'm using MVC Core as well.

Comment: I use a combination of EF and ADO.NET.  I use EF for basic CRUD operations and other non-complicated queries (this saves you from having 100s of simple stored procedures like the old days).  For queries with complicated joins or CTEs, I use stored procedures and call them with ADO.NET.  ADO.NET is much more efficient than EF.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link explaining how to get started with ADO.NET and MVC Core would you?

Comment: I would not try to learn ADO.NET in an MVC Core application because that too is pre-release and there is little to no documentation on it.  [Here is a tutorial that will get you started](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET).  Using ADO.NET in ASP.NET Core is very similar but not exactly the same.

Comment: I really appreciate the help man.  If I were to downgrade the project, what version of MVC and EF would you recommend?  I have VS 2015.

Comment: No problem.  I wouldn't downgrade the project.  I would create a new standard **ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** project that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1.  Then after you've got ADO.NET working you can work on finding the equivalent namespaces in ADO.NET Core.  When you get to that point, post another question on SO.  Maybe I'll see it and post some sample code.  But you need to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fake entity for the result of your stored procedure. You can set any property as the Key, even if in the results of the stored procedure the key values are not unique.

For example if you have a table like the following :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[banana_hoard]
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    [owner] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    [bananas]  BIGINT NOT NULL
)
```

You can have a query that does not return the row id like this :

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MonkeyDbContext())
        {
            var sp_results = db.search.FromSql(@"execute <YOUR_STORED_PROC>");
            str_result = String.Join("\n", sp_results.Select(a => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a) ));
            Console.WriteLine("stored proc result :\n" + str_result);
        }
    }
}

public class MonkeyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StoredProcRow> search { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\monkey_db;Database=monkey_db;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}

public class StoredProcRow
{
    [Key]
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public long Bananas { get; set; }
}
```